# Restart batch job/step in case of some type exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have the operation in the step/reader which can throw some Exception which extends RuntimeException. I need to restart this step, in case this exception has been throwed. I'm tried something like that:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRetryPolicy createSimpleRetryPolicy() {
    Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(Exception.class, true);
    return new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, map, true);
}
```

```
@Bean
public Step statisticsImportStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, PageStatusFetcherReader reader, PageStatusFetcherProcessor processor, PageStatusFetcherWriter writer, TaskExecutor taskExecutor, SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("statisticsImportStep")
            .<String, String>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .faultTolerant()
            .retryPolicy(simpleRetryPolicy)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .throttleLimit(20)
            .build();
}
```

but in this way I received:

> org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException:
>   Non-skippable exception during read

Any idea how to restart this job?(I can't try{}catch() exception in the reader)
upd: It doesn't want to restart any type of the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an `ExceptionHandler` to retry managed `Exception`. It seems a default implementation already exists : [`SimpleRetryExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/SimpleRetryExceptionHandler.html).

This should work like the XML :

```
<skippable-exception-classes>
    <include class="xx.xx.xx.Exception"/>
</skippable-exception-classes>
```

You can try to add it this with : `exceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)`

I couldn't find any example of how to actually use it though :(